# Rendering a component with router in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

My first day with Vue. I initialized my app. I want to add a Login component, when I set routes in main.js, no page works.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import Login from './components/Login.vue'

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: App },
  { path: '/login', component: Login }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes 
})

new Vue({
  router
}).$mount("#app")
```

Only works when I add render option to Vue object and renders the App component.

```
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App) // or Login
}).$mount("#app")
```

How will I ensure rendering route components?

Answer (score 2):

You should add `router-view` component inside your `App` component like :

```
<template>
   <div>
     <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Great thank you. Now, I can't see content of Login, what I see is only template of App.vue.

Comment: you could visit the link `youbaseUrl/login` something like `http://127.0.0.1:8080/login` please check this [full example](https://codesandbox.io/s/qx3orn736q?file=/App.vue)